# Call API JSON through PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to call API, which returns JSON data.

```
$jsondataom6 = file_get_contents( 'https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId='.$networkid.'&Target=Affiliate_OfferUrl&Method=findAll&api_key='.$apikey.'&filters%5Boffer_id%5D='.$offer_id.'&fields%5B%5D=offer_url&fields%5B%5D=name&fields%5B%5D=id');
$dataom6 = json_decode($jsondataom6,true);
```

it returns with

```
Warning: file_get_contents( https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId=icubes&Target=Affiliate_Offer&Method=generateTrackingLink&api_key=fc688817e96b4ff2da577837210a2790c7bba0c8fd09f9bde3c7573e49604ae6&offer_id=2): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\SCRIPT\admin\api.php on line 484
```

When I click on the link above, it works perfectly. I really don't getting my mistake. Is there anyone who help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your question, but I think your URL string is not good..
try to convert "%5B" to "[" and "%5D" to "]".. dont copy url parameters from browser.. write them by your self.

try this:

```
$jsondataom6 = file_get_contents( 'https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId='.$networkid.'&Target=Affiliate_OfferUrl&Method=findAll&api_key='.$apikey.'&filters[offer_id]='.$offer_id.'&fields[]=offer_url&fields[]=name&fields[]=id');
```

Comment: I am using api here , In api documentation there is same link as I post here,So I do not copy from browser.But still I will check for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this quotes " instead of ', I think you are escaping them.

Try if you are escaping using echo, and paste the filename there.

Comment: I tried same,I paste the filename there,I am getting proper result

Comment: So could you mark my questiom as correct. I would be thankful :-)